# How can I mimic a C# project structure in Typescript?

Tags: c#, typescript

In C#, a library's source is arranged in a project that compiles down into a DLL. The DLL's interface exposes a subset of classes and functions that actually implement the library. Objects that are invisible to clients outside of the library are labeled `internal`.

I'm wondering what the equivalent of a Typescript "DLL" would look like. Typescript files with imports are modules and expose only what you want to importing files with `export`. However, I'm not aware of any Typescript equivalents to C#'s `internal`.

The closest approximation I can think of to this idea is compiling and bundling a Typescript project into a single .js file that in turn exports only the parts of the library you want to expose—a higher-level export, if you will. But how would you create this sort of project/workflow?

I've done a number of searches on this topic and haven't found a lot of info. Maybe I'm using the wrong words. Maybe I'm thinking too much like a C# programmer!

Comment: `internal` is a difficult concept to reproduce in JavaScript since in theory the entire codebase can be minified into a single file and the types of boundaries you'd expect to exist in C# don't have a natural counterpart in Typescript, particularly `internal`, `protected`, and `protected internal`.  In this case I'd treat non-exported modules as `private` instead of `internal` and expect that anything exported is part of the `public` api..

Comment: @DavidL That's difficult to do when you're trying to keep 1 class to a file. It's even more difficult when your project size is larger than the typical Javascript library.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  I typically structure my TypeScript applications (and AngularJS js applications) as one class / structure per file.  with `export` functionality, that still minimizes the publicly exposed API. And you can always take it further.  You can group classes into modules and expose only a subset of the api via those module exports, which gives you something similar to a dll.

Comment: @DavidL Ok, that's what I was originally thinking about in my question—a "master" module that exports the public API. That sounds like a very reasonable approach. I assume, in this case, the files aren't actually bundled. So, if a client issuing the library really wanted to, they could try to use some of the internals. I was under the impression that the only way to prevent that was to bundle everything together.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering what the equivalent of a Typescript "DLL" would look like

An node module (also called npm module).

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question. I followed the link, and all I got out of it was "Compile your Typescript and add a .d.ts".